# React-router Passing data to component/adding to store and route to new component with the data

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I'm quite new to React and Redux and Routes. I'm making use of redux store to render a ToDoList with multiple Todos. My goal is to create a New ToDo with some additional input. It must be a New Todo, I do not want to change the original Todo.

On selection of 1 ToDo from the list, there is an input box is shown. A New Todo 
consist of the input together with props from the selected Todo. After creation of my New Todo, I want to be routed to the another page with my New Todo created (it must be in another page).

Current stage: Routes already been form. I'm already displaying the Todos too. I do not know how to pass the selected Todo + (input) to the next page.

**TodoList.js**

```
@connect((store) => {
    return {
        todos: store.todos.todos,
    }
})

class TodoList extends React.Component {
render() {    
    const todos = todos.map(todo => <Todo key={todo.id} name={todo.text} id={todo.id} />)

return (
    <div>
        {todos}
    </div>
}
```

**ToDo.js**

```
class ToDo extends Component {

handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Get <input /> value
    // Get props

    // Create a New Todo with selected props and <input /> value for my store.
    // *Route to new page* that will display props and <input /> from store. 
}
render(){
    {this.props.name}
    <input />
    <button className="btn " onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>Create</button>
}
}
```

Is my approach correct? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you and have a great day.